# How to mark notification as read after I receive cloud kit response?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

From CloudKit I receive example response:

```
[AnyHashable("aps"): {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("ck"): {
    ce = 2;
    cid = "iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice";
    nid = "bb501155-f914-4f8b-b58e-4c24921727f5";
    qry =     {
        dbs = 2;
        fo = 3;
        rid = "27C8C222-11B3-4831-A125-EAFEF8DB6ADD";
        sid = "E32D6B20-3F81-464E-ACA8-2DD29FA93CF3";
        zid = "_defaultZone";
        zoid = "_defaultOwner";
    };
}]
```

At any time I can fetch missed notifications and mark them as read to prevent from receiving it again.

Simply I do it like this:

```
OperationQueue().addOperation(CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation(notificationIDsToMarkRead: [queryNotification.notificationID!]))
```

**nid** field links to notification connected with this response.

After I receive CloudKit response I need to mark this notification as read. All I have is `String`, but operation to mark it as read expects `CKNotificationID` object. How can I create such object?